# Component-changes.json not found SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, odata, sapui5

I am getting below error in console, everytime I am creating any project and I am not able to fix it.. I tried creating this file in different folders but still same error.. I have seen some of the threads which are opened for this Error on SCN but none of them worked for me. In my case app is not showing data.

I deployed the app on Git but it doesn't resolved. please help me.. This error I never got earlier.[image]

Comment: Once the application is moved to Gateway server , the error wont appear , don't know what is the the reason behind that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create a "Component-changes.json" file in the same folder in that your index.html is located. inside your component-changes.json goes `{}`.

Comment: Thanks much for help.. but I am still not sure why this file is required. I have never seen this before..

Comment: please see https://help.sap.com/saphelp_uiaddon10/helpdata/en/a8/e55aa2f8bc4127923b20685a6d1621/frameset.htm.

Comment: Followed the same steps above but the error still exist

Comment: please check the spelling of Component-changes.json. with a capital C. please check that an opening curly bracket and closing curly bracket {} are inside of component-changes.json.